# User should only see Dashboard, should not see report link or should restrict to see the associated report

Tags: dashboard

There dashboard is visible to user. I want to restrict user to see the report link in dashboard. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, It's not possible I think. In SFDC, It's default the `dashboard component` having the `report link` in bottom section(which used in that dashboard component). which is helpful for the users whom creates the dashboard to update the report filters and change the visualization for the data (if need) with in that window.

So if you need to restrict the dashboard viewing user to edit the report (which used in that dashboard component) means, please update the user's access for the report into **Viewer Access**.

Please let me know if it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @MohanRaj.